# Python deep copy a list into itself n times recursively

Tags: python, list, recursion, copy

I need to append a deep copy (not a reference) of list to itslef recursively n times, for example for

```
n=0 -> []
n = 1 -> [[]]
n=2 -> [[], [[]]] 
and so forth.
```

this is what I wrote so far:

```
def magic_list(n: int) -> List[Any]:
    #take only positive numbers
    assert(n>=0)
    
    if n == 0:
        return []
    else:
        return magic_list_helper(0, n, [])
```

the main function, I have to keep this def signature exactly the same(takes only n:int).
this is the helper function I wrote:

```
def magic_list_helper(index: int,threshold:int ,lst:List[Any]) -> List[Any]:
    if index >= threshold:
        return lst
    
    else:
        
        # temp_lst = deepcopy(lst)
        # lst.append(temp_lst)
        return magic_list_helper(index + 1, threshold, lst)
```

for this problem I cannot use `copy.deepcopy` or any other external libraries(thats why its with #, without it it works) and I could not find a solution online without deep copy. Also I cannot use List comprehension, slicing or any O(n) operations on lists(I can use append). Hope you can help me,
thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to have to write your own version of `deepcopy()`. Are there any constraints on the initial contents of the list?

Comment: Yes, this function takes an int n and returns a list like the examples I gave(empty ones) so it does not need to deal with the lists content.

Comment: But if it needs to make a deep copy of the original list, it does need to deal with the list content.

Comment: Or are you always just creating empty lists, there's no original list to copy?

Comment: Yes, just create empty lists and append them, I added the code for clarification.

Comment: What is the result for n = 3? I have code that returns `[[[]], [[], [[]]]]`, is that correct?

Comment: I have another version that returns `[[], [[]], [[], [[]]]]`. I suspect that's the correct one.

Comment: no, its suppose to be ```[[], [[]], [[], [[]]]]```

Comment: @Barmar yes thats correct

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Not sure if it's the correct one.

```
l=[]
n=2
for i in range(n):
    l.append(l.copy())
print(l)
```

Comment: This makes shallow copies, not deep copies.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make copies. Each call can use a list comprehension that executes `n` times, calling itself recursively. The list comprehension creates new lists of the appropriate lengths.

You don't even need to check for the base case, because when `n == 0` the list comprehension will return an empty list.

```
def magic_list(n: int) -> List[Any]:
    return [magic_list(x) for x in range(n)]

for i in range(5): print(magic_list(i))

[]
[[]]
[[], [[]]]
[[], [[]], [[], [[]]]]
[[], [[]], [[], [[]]], [[], [[]], [[], [[]]]]]
```

Comment: Im so sorry for your trouble and thank you for your answer, but I forgot to say that we cannot use o(n) action on lists and also list comprehension and slicing.

Comment: It's possible to transform any loop into recursion. So you should be able to write a recursive helper function that replaces the list comprehension. I'm not going to try to work it out, that seems to be the point of the exercise for you.

Comment: See [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/279004/general-way-to-convert-a-loop-while-for-to-recursion-or-from-a-recursion-to-a) for example

Answer (score 0):

Using [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) is the foundation for recursive problem solving -

1. If `n` is less than or equal to zero, the work is done. Return the empty result, `[]`
2. (inductive) `n` is at least 1 (positive). Find the result of the sub-problem, `magic_list(n - 1)` and concatenate it to the singleton list of the same sub-problem, `[magic_list(n - 1)]`

```py
# write
def magic_list(n):
  if n <= 0: return []
  return magic_list(n - 1) + [magic_list(n - 1)]
```

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. That means avoiding things like mutation (`.append`), variable reassignments, and other side effects.

```py
# test
for n in range(5):
  print(magic_list(n))
```

```py
# output
[]
[[]]
[[], [[]]]
[[], [[]], [[], [[]]]]
[[], [[]], [[], [[]]], [[], [[]], [[], [[]]]]]
```

In the above program, you can see the sub-problem `magic_list(n - 1)` is calculated twice. We cut the work in half by assigning the result to a variable -

```py
# optimize
def magic_list(n):
  if n == 0: return []
  m = magic_list(n - 1) # ✏️
  return m + [m]        #
```